# how to deselect other listBoxes when 1 is selected

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have 3 listBoxes and I want to deselect others when 1 of them is selected. How can I do this?
I have tried setting the focused property to false, but c# doesn't allow assigning to the focused property.

Comment: Why would you change the focus property if what you want to change is the selection. Here is what Focus is in 3.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have three list boxes, do the following. This code will clear the selection of every other list box when a particular list box changes selections. You can clear a list box selection by setting its `SelectedIndex = -1`.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}

private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox2.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}

private void listBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox3.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

The `if (listBox#.SelectedIndex > -1)` is necessary because setting the `SelectedIndex` of a list box via code will also trigger its `SelectedIndexChanged` event, which would otherwise cause all list boxes to clear any time one of them was selected.

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, if you only have those three list boxes on your form, then you could consolidate it into one method. Link all three list boxes to this event method:

```
private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox thisListBox = sender as ListBox;
    if (thisListBox == null || thisListBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (ListBox loopListBox in this.Controls)
    {
        if (thisListBox != loopListBox)
        {
            loopListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @Devin Burke's answer, so you don't have to worry having other controls in the form:

```
using System.Linq;
private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox thisListBox = sender as ListBox;
    if (thisListBox == null || thisListBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (ListBox loopListBox in this.Controls.OfType<ListBox>().ToList())
    {
        if (thisListBox != loopListBox)
        {
            loopListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my little NET5/Winforms app, the selected item of the current listbox won't stay blue/marked.

I found the solution for that is restoring focus back and set the index. Improving on the generic solution with a proper type check, Nane's answer,

```
    private void lbDefect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
       ListBox thisListBox = sender as ListBox;
       if (thisListBox == null || thisListBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
          return;
        }
       var iSelected = thisListBox.SelectedIndex; // keep position..
       foreach (ListBox loopListBox in this.Controls.OfType<ListBox>().ToList())
       {
         if (thisListBox != loopListBox)
         {
           loopListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
         }
       }
       // .. and this will show the selection for the current listbox
       thisListBox.Focus();
       thisListBox.SelectedIndex = iSelected;
    }
```