# How to set SeletedItems = null in a Listbox if i select a other Listbox

Tags: c#, mvvm, listbox

basically i'm trying to do [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178067/how-to-deselect-other-listboxes-when-1-is-selected)

but you can see it is not MVVM so i'm looking for a way to set `SeletedItems = null` or `clear()` depending on what's doable

because in my View i will got N `ListBoxes` and if he pressed a `Button` after selecting some Items i will change some properties of the `SeletedItems` but only for the last active `Listbox`

so i decided to use on `SelectedItems` Property for all the `Listboxes`  but it doesn't work based on 2 problems i can't bind to to `SelectedItems` and based on this i can't test how to remove the selection from the other `Listboxes`

---

### EDIT:

to give you an simple example:

XAML

```
    <Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox  Width="432" Height="67"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      SelectionMode="Extended"   
<!-- SeletedItems="{Binding SelectedListItems}" ??? -->       
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Collection1}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}"
                                       Background="{Binding MyBackground}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <ListBox  Width="432" Height="67"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      SelectionMode="Extended"
<!-- SeletedItems="{Binding SelectedListItems}" ??? -->     
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Collection2}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}"
                                       Background="{Binding MyBackground}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <Button Content="unselect" Width="80" Height="150"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Window>
```

Code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new VM();
        }
    }

    public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<DetailVM> _SelectedListItems = new ObservableCollection<DetailVM>();
        public ObservableCollection<DetailVM> SelectedListItems
        {
            get { return _SelectedListItems; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedListItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedListItems");
            }
        }

        public List<DetailVM> Collection1 { get; set; }
        public List<DetailVM> Collection2 { get; set; }

        private RelayCommand _myCommand;
        public ICommand MyCommand
        {
            get { return _myCommand?? (_myCommand= new RelayCommand(param => OnMyCommand())); }
        }
        public void OnMyCommand()
        {
            foreach DetailVM item in SelectedListItems
            {
                item.MyBackground ="Red";
            }
        }

        public VM()
        {
            Collection1 = new List<DetailVM>();
            Collection2 = new List<DetailVM>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Collection1.Add(new DetailVM { MyText = "C1ITEM " + i });
                Collection2.Add(new DetailVM { MyText = "C2ITEM " + i });
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Member

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class DetailVM
    {
        public string MyText { get; set; }
        public string MyBackground { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The code above should change the color of the Textbox background to Red 
if the user selected some Items in a Listbox and he should only be able to seleted Items in one Listbox at the same time

so how to do this? (bear in mind this is a simple example but i need this for N Listboxes which will be generated over a template)

Comment: Your questions a little confusing as-is, can you try and be more clear? Maybe add the code/xaml you have currently?

Comment: hi i edited my Question i hop it's now more clear what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would recommend you to extend ListView so that it includes a bindable SelectedValues property (you cannot use the name SelectedItems since it's already a non-bindable property of ListView). Here's an example of how this can be achieved.

```
public class MultiSelectListView : ListView
{
// Using a DependencyProperty as backing store
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValuesProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValues", typeof(IList), typeof(MultiSelectListView), new PropertyMetadata(default(IList), OnSelectedItemsChanged));

public IList SelectedValues
{
  get { return (IList)GetValue(SelectedValuesProperty); }
  set { SetValue(SelectedValuesProperty, value); }
}


private static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // if selected items list implements INotifyCollectionChanged, we subscribe to its CollectionChanged event
  var element = (MultiSelectListView)d;
  if (e.OldValue != null && e.OldValue is INotifyCollectionChanged)
  {
    var list = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    list.CollectionChanged -= element.OnCollectionChanged;
  }
  if (e.NewValue is INotifyCollectionChanged)
  {
    var list = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    list.CollectionChanged += element.OnCollectionChanged;
  }

}

// when selection changes in the view, elements are added or removed from the underlying list
protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (SelectedValues != null)
  {
    foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
    {
      if (!SelectedValues.Contains(item))
        SelectedValues.Add(item);
    }
    foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
    {
      if (SelectedValues.Contains(item))
        SelectedValues.Remove(item);
    }
  }
  base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
}

// when underlying list changes, we set the control's selected items to the contents of the list
void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (SelectedValues != null)
  {
    SetSelectedItems(SelectedValues);
  }
}

}
```

Once you've done this you can control the behavior of a list's selected items through the viewmodel. Clearing the viewmodel list clears the selected items in the control.

Next you can subscribe to the collection changed event of your selected items lists (in the view model) and in the handler check whether you need to clear any of your lists.

Comment: i can't change an ObservableCollection in the CollectionChangedEvent `Error:Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged event.`

Comment: Are you tring to change the same collection that triggered the collectionchanged event?

Comment: i try to change my `SelectedListItems` , which triggers my collectionchanged , to remove all items which are not in the current selected ListBox